# How is this crc calculated correctly?

Tags: embedded, spi, crc

I'm looking for help. The chip I'm using via SPI (MAX22190) specifies:

CRC polynom: x5 + x4 + x2 + x0

CRC is calculated using the first 19 data bits padded with the 5-bit initial word 00111.

The 5-bit CRC result is then appended to the original data bits to create the 24-bit SPI data frame.

**The CRC result I calculated with multiple tools is: 0x18**

**However, the chip shows an CRC error on this. It expects: 0x0F**

Can anybody tell me where my calculations are going wrong?

**My input data (19 data bits) is:**

19-bit data:

0x04      0x00      0x00

0000 0100 0000 0000 000

**24-bit, padded with init value:**

0x38      0x20      0x00

0011 1000 0010 0000 0000 0000

=> Data sent by me: 0x38      0x20      0x18

=> Data expected by chip: 0x38 0x20 0x0F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRC algorithm is explained [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/6798.html).
I think your error comes from 00111 padding that must be padded on the right side instead on the left.

Comment: As it turns out, the manufacturer describes its algorithm in detail over here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/6798.html Seems like your assumption about right-padding the init value is right.